# Is it possible to upload a form without filling certain attributes in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i just want to know is it possible to upload a form without filling some attribute into MySQL? I want to upload user form which they can fill in to sent their application, but in admin side, the form they sent will have another column which is remarks, there the admin can reject the application then fill in the remarks why they are rejected to store in database. the admin can edit it. i tried to set the value into null, however, when I want to put remarks on the rejected candidate, it doesnt not save inside database, it still shows null

**function for store data**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
    
        'fullname' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'contact' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'attachment' => 'required',
        'remarks' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:500'],
    ]);


    $candidate = new MainForm();
    $candidate->fullname = $request->fullname;
    $candidate->email = $request->email;
    $candidate->contact = $request->contact;
    $candidate->address  = $request->address ;
    $candidate->attachment = $request->attachment;
    $candidate->remarks  = $request->remarks ;
   
   
        if
        ($file = $request->hasFile('attachment')) {
            $file = $request->file('attachment');
 
            $filename = time() . '.' .$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/documents/');
 
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $candidate->attachment = $filename;
        }

        $candidate->save();
        
        return back();
}
```

below is my database code

```
  $table->id();
        $table->string('fullname');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->longText('contact');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('attachment');
        $table->string('remarks')->default(NULL);
        $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
```

and below is my blade file, which i can display the candidate details and once i open the remarks button, it will give me a modal in which i can put my remarks there.

```
                        <div class="flex justify-center items-center">
                        <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#remarks-modal-preview" class="flex items-center mr-3"><i  class="w-4 h-4 mr-1"></i> Remarks</a>

                        <div class="modal" id="remarks-modal-preview">

                            <div class="modal__content">
                                <div class="intro-y flex items-center p-5">
                                    <h2 class="text-lg font-medium mr-auto">
                                        Remarks
                                    </h2>
                                </div>
                                <form method="post" action="{{ route('mainform') }}">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="intro-y box p-5">
                                   
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="fullname"
                                                class="input w-full border col-span-4 form-control" value="{{ $candidate->fullname}}" readonly >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email"
                                                class="input w-full border col-span-4 form-control" value="{{ $candidate->email}}" readonly >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Phone Number</label>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="contact" name="contact"
                                                class="input w-full border col-span-4 form-control" value="{{ $candidate->contact}}" readonly >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Address</label>
                                        <div class="mt-2">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="address" name="address"
                                                class="input w-full border col-span-4 form-control" value="{{ $candidate->address}}" readonly >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                               
                                    <div class="mt-3">
                                        <label>Remarks</label>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="remarks" name="remarks"
                                     class="input w-full border col-span-4 form-control tail-select" value="{{ $candidate->remarks}}">
                                            </div>
                              
                                    
                                    <div class="text-right mt-5">
                                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal"
                                            class="button w-24 border dark:border-dark-5 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300 mr-1">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="button w-24 bg-theme-1 text-white">Save</button>
                                        
            
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

Comment: The PHP code you've posted contains no reference to a `Remarks` field anywhere.

Comment: i update my question

Comment: Have you updated `MainForm::save()` too?

Comment: yes, i've updated it

Comment: You're saying that the model is stored successfully, but updating is a problem. So why are you showing us code to store a new model? Where is your code to update the existing model?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Lot's of problems with your code but the main problem is the route in your web form (`{{ route('mainform') }}`) doesn't point to the route in your route file (`Route::post('/edit{id}', 'GeneralRejectedController@update')->name('generalrejected.update');`).

---

In your Laravel migration, the correct way to mark a column as nullable is to use the `nullable()` method.

**Instead of:**

```
 $table->string('remarks')->default(NULL);
```

**You should use:**

```
 $table->string('remarks')->nullable();
```

[Laravel Documentation: Nullable column modifier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-modifiers)

---

**In your controller form validation, don't forget to specify the column can be nullable:**

```
$validated = $request->validate([
    ...
    'remark' => 'nullable'|'string'|'min:5'|'max:500',
    ....
]);
```

[Laravel documentation: Validating optional fields.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#a-note-on-optional-fields)

---

That's all there's to it. If you still can't save your "remarks" field, you probably have a problem elsewhere. You can inspect the content of your request in your controller with `dd($request->all())`.

---

Looking at your controller update() method. There's a lot of problems because you didn't follow Laravel best practices.

1. It doesn't make sense to call your model `MainForm`, if I understand your app, it should be called `Candidate`.
2. You should always validate user inputs before saving to the database, don't save the request values, save the validated values.
3. Use Laravel Eloquent to create object. Instead of creating object with `new Object()` (never do this) you should use dependency injection and do something like `$candidate->create($validated)`.
4. You should use CRUD named routes. If your Controller method is `update` your route should be `candidates.update`. It doesn't make sense to call your route `mainform`.

Here is how your controller should look like (not tested but it's a starting point):

```
    public function update(Request $request, Candidate $candidate) // Update your route to pass the Candidate object instead of the ID.
    {
        // dd($request->all()); // Use this to debug your request

        $validated = $request->validate([
            'fullname' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'contact' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'attachment' => 'required',
            'remarks' => ['nullable', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:500'],
        ]);

        $candidate->update($validated);

        // You should validate your file before storing to your drive. This could be a vulnerability.
        if ($file = $request->hasFile('attachment')) {
            $file = $request->file('attachment');

            $filename = time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/documents/');

            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $candidate->attachment = $filename;
        }

        return back();
    }
```

Comment: tried dd but why it is not giving me the output? it back to the original site. where should i put it?

Comment: @kins Put it in your "mainform" controller. Can you also share your controller code?

Comment: @kins Thanks. Can you please also post your routes files? (`web.php`)

Comment: Route::post('/edit{id}', 'GeneralRejectedController@update')->name('generalrejected.update');

Comment: @kins In your web form you use a different route. `<form method="post" action="{{ route('mainform') }}">`  That's your problem.

Comment: @kins I have update my answer. I recommend you to follow the Laracast tutorial "getting started with Laravel". Also read about CRUD, Laravel naming conventions, and Laravel best practice.

Comment: i've changed my route to generalrejected.update. but still not working, since this is my first project using laravel so yes i am lacking a lot

Comment: @kins There's too many issues for me to help further. You're on the right path but you need to follow the Laravel way of doing things. I recommend you check out Laracast getting started tutorial, it's free and you'll be able to resolve all the problem you're having now. Good luck you can do it!